# How to handle a List, Collection or IEnumerable in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi all can anyone help me ... Im very new to c# and mvc

The **Model** is:

```
public class CatagoryModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  CName { get; set; }
}
```

The **Controller** is:

```
   public ActionResult catagory() {
        var c = new CatagoryModel();
        var URL="";

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URL)
                   as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                      as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }


        var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CatagoryModel>>(result);

        return View(categories);
      }
```

The **View** like this

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CatagoryModel
<ul>
@foreach(var k in Model){
   <li>@k.Id</li> 
    <li>@k.CName</li>

}
```

And i dont know what went wrong ...
It shows an error while rendering the view ..

Comment: I'd also recommend [creating a ViewModel specific to the view that encapsulates your view's needs and is extensible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if your model is `Enumerable`, in your view, it must be enumerable !

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.CatagoryModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is a list of `CategoryModel`, not a single `CategoryModel`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.CatagoryModel>
```